# Search a java.util.List starting at a specific index

Tags: java, list, collections, indexof

Is there a built-in method to search a java.util.List specifying the first item to start the search from? Like you can do with [Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

I know I can easily implement something on my own, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if Java or http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/package-summary.html already has it.

**I'm not asking how to implement this, I'm asking whether something is already available** A lot of the suggestions here were buggy.

**If anybody cares for receiving credit for the right answer, please update your answer to say that there is not a built-in way to do it (if you know for sure)**

Here's what I would like to do

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
// Add some values to the list here
// Search starting from the 6th item in the list
strings.indexOf("someValue", 5);
```

Right now I'm using

```
/**
 * This is like List.indexOf(), except that it allows you to specify the index to start the search from
 */
public static int indexOf(List<?> list, Object toFind, int startingIndex) {
    for (int index = startingIndex; index < list.size(); index++) {
        Object current = list.get(index);
        if (current != null && current.equals(toFind)) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And I've also implemented it as

```
public static int indexOf(List<?> list, Object toFind, int startingIndex) {
    int index = list.subList(startingIndex).indexOf(toFind);
    return index == -1 ? index : index + startingIndex;
}
```

Comment: Writing a two lines loop isn't really reinventing the wheel. That's better than to integrate a lib just for this. That's more clear for the maintainer. And that's of course much more efficient than most other solutions creating new objects.

Comment: @dystroy I'm already using Apache Commons, I'm not going to integrate a library just for this

Comment: @JuanMendes Your second implementation is very good: it relies on the standard Java stuff as much as it can. You can combine the first two lines for a very efficient and easy to read implementation.

Comment: @dystroy I do think it is reinventing the wheel, specially since the code is potentially buggy, as evidenced by the bugs in the suggestions here (most have been fixed after they were told about it)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No not a single method, but there is a simple documented way of doing this with 1-2 lines of code. It even says so [in the documentation for this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29):

```
strings.subList(5, strings.size()).indexOf("someValue");
```

Possibly add 5 to the result (if not -1), depending on if you want to keep that sublist around or not etc:

```
int result = list.subList(startIndex, list.size()).indexOf(someValue);
return result== -1 ? -1 : result+startIndex;
```

Note:
`subList` does *not* create a new `List`, just a view into the original one.

Comment: keep in mind that the returned "indexOf" is relative to the sublist, and you should add to the starting point of your sublist:  int index = start + strings.subList(start, strings.size()).indexOf("someValue");

Comment: I know how to do it (it's not that hard), the question is whether I have to do it on my own

Comment: @JuanMendes what do you mean? This is in the List api.

Comment: @Mattias I mean I know how to do it. I'm wondering if there already is a method that works just like `String.indexOf` and I don't have to add extra code. Do I have to create a method so I don't duplicate the logic everywhere, or is it already wrapped in a method by a library?

Comment: @JuanMendes again what in the proposed solution in this answer is your own method? This *is* the way to do indexOf starting from a specified index. This as explicitly stated in the documentation (linked in the answer). Everyone assumed you knew that there is no indexOf with an additional index argument as everyone can plainly see that from the List API docs (linked in the answer as well) as well as code completion in your favorite IDE.

Comment: @Mattias The method I'm looking for is not necessarily a method of java.util.List I obviously already checked that. There could be a utility static helper that I didn't find. My only question is: am I duplicating existing code in Java or Apache Commons by rolling out my own method like I mentioned above?

Comment: Well, there is and it is `myList.subList(startIndex, myList.size()).indexOf("...")` :). If you want to wrap that in a method of it's own, sure go ahead, but it's 1-2 lines of code (2 if you want to handle the element not present). Not much of a readability improvement really.

Comment: @Mattias You can see from other people's suggestions that there are at least two things you can forget when implementing this on your own: add to starting index and check for -1. Therefore, I do think a method is necessary so that everybody who needs to search within a list starting from an index it doesn't have to encounter those bugs on their own. You keep trying to tell me that it is built-in, but you have to add some potentially buggy code to make it really work...

Comment: Sounds like a decent reason, can use `static import` as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sublist`, like this:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
// Add values ...
int start = 5;
int pos = strings.sublist(start, strings.size()).indexOf("someValue");
// Don't forget to add the starting point back
if (pos >= 0) pos += start;
```

Comment: Again, my question is not how to implement it, it just seemed that if there's already a built-in way for Strings, that there would be one for Lists too.

Comment: @JuanMendes No, lists do not offer this functionality, and neither do collections. Your second implementation uses as much of the standard library as it could, and it's only two lines long (assuming that you combine the first two lines into one) so it is probably as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

For a more generic approach, try this method:

```
public static int indexOf(List<?> list, int start, Object value) {
    int idx = list.subList(start, list.size()).indexOf(value);
    return idx != -1 ? idx + start : -1;
}
```

It will work for lists of any type, returning `-1` if no element was found. Use it like this:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c");
int idx = indexOf(strings, 2, "a");
System.out.println(idx);
> 3
```

Comment: This will not return the right value if the item is not found.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight there, fixed it!

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I was not asking how to implement it, it's the correct code but not the answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `subList(int from, int to)` and `indexOf`, like that:

```
int pos = strings.subList(5, strings.size()).indexOf("someValue");
if (pos >= 0) {
    pos += 5;
}
```