# Java ArrayList sublist giving wrong result

Tags: java

I am trying to find the index of an element after a particular position in ArrayList in Java as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938364/search-a-java-util-list-starting-at-a-specific-index) question. Below is my implementation:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class palindrome{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int[] array = Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
        int n=array[0];
        List<StringBuilder> ls=new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
        while(n-->0){
            ls.add(new StringBuilder(br.readLine()));
        }
        StringBuilder rev=ls.get(1).reverse();
        System.out.println(rev);
        int i=1;
        System.out.println(ls.subList(i+1,ls.size()).indexOf(rev));
    }
}
```

I'm giving below input to the program

```
4 2
oo
ox
xx
xo
```

so, the logic is that I am trying to find the index of reverse of 'ox', which should return 3, but the code always returns -1. I cannot spot any error. Please tell me if you guys have spotted any error.

Thank You!

Comment: so simply: remove the counting code for a moment, and test it with hardcoded knowledge of the fact that you're only going to be inputting `ox`. And then step through it with debugging turned on: what happens at each line?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm using simple text editor. I cannot do debugging. I am hardcoding 'xo' inside indexOf

Comment: Then step one is to start using a proper code editor. Whether it's Eclipse or VS Code, real code editors help you solve problems rather than needing to ask people to help you, so: now is the best time to start using one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StringBuilder`s are work-in-progress strings being built and as such they don't override `equals()`. A string builder will only compare equal to itself. It's never equal to any other builders, not even ones with the same contents.

That means that `indexOf()` won't work because it relies on `equals()`. If you want this to work you need to use plain `String`s rather than `StringBuilder`s. For example:

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
while (n-- > 0) {
    ls.add(br.readLine());
}
String rev = new StringBuilder(ls.get(1)).reverse().toString();
```

Or, if you want to stick with `StringBuilder`s you can, you'll just have to forego the `indexOf()` method and look for the matching string yourself with a manual `for` loop.